# Remove Close Button $host.ui.PromptForCredential in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a prompt for credential script in my script block, how do i ensure i disable or remove the 'X' close button on the right? The reason i want to do this is that clicking on 'X' opens up another powershell prompt that i dont recognize and closing the 'X' exits my script. The Complete code can be found below and the image for reference.

[ScreenShot for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZXU.png)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TS_Deploy_Group = "MYADGROUP"
$get_AD_Server = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetWorkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.DNSDomain -like "***-**.contoso.com"}).DnsDomain      
$retry = $false
if($get_AD_Server -eq $null)
{
do
{
$msgboxinput = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Please check if you are connected to corporate Network`nClick'OK' to Retry`n'Cancel' to Reboot", 'Unable to Contact AD', 'OKCancel', 'Error')
switch($msgboxinput)
{
'OK'
{
$retry = $true
}
'Cancel'
{
Start-Process -FilePath "wpeutil" -ArgumentList "reboot"
        }
    }
}until($get_AD_Server -ne $null)
}

if($get_AD_Server -ne $null) 
{
$get_Nearest_DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $get_AD_Server -Discover -NextClosestSite).Name
$AD_Server = $get_Nearest_DC,$get_AD_Server -join "."
$pwd = $false
do{
$cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Please enter your Operator Credentials", "", "")
try{
$ADauth = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TS_Deploy_Group -Recursive -Server $AD_Server -Credential $cred
}
Catch [System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException]      
{       
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please check the admin user name or password", "Invalid credentials")          
}
Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] 
{       
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The user  " + $cred.username + "  has not been found", "User not found")                                                       
}   
Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException] 
{       
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Check the server name or IP configuration", "Error while contacting AD Server")    
}
<#if (($ADauth.name -Contains $cred.username) -ne $true) {
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The user  " + $cred.username + "  has not been found", "User not found")
}#> 
if (($cred.UserName -eq $null) -and ($cred.Password -eq $null))
{
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Credentials cannot be empty")
}
If(($ADauth.name -Contains $cred.username) -ne $true)
 {
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The specified user is not member of the group: $TS_Deploy_Group", "Unauthorized user")
    }
if (($ADauth.SamAccountName -Contains $cred.username) -eq $true) {
#[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The user  " + $cred.username + "  has not been found", "User not found")
Start-Process -FilePath "mshta" -ArgumentList "X:\Windows\system32\Name_of_HTA.hta" -Wait
$pwd = $true
}
<#else {
Start-Process -FilePath "mshta" -ArgumentList "X:\Windows\system32\Name_of_HTA.hta" -Wait
$pwd = $true
}#>
}Until($pwd -eq $true)
}
```

Comment: The close button has the same effect as the `Cancel` button. Why do you want to remove it? Because it might be unclear to users what it does? Trying to remove it, if possible at all, would require a lot of effort that is probably better spent on implementing your own dialog.

Comment: The short answer is _no_, Windows PowerShell offloads construction of the prompt to `credui.dll` and there's nothing in the API that would allow you to control the window buttons. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What does $Cred contain if the close button is pressed? What does $Cred contain if Cancel is pressed?  You could put the prompt in a loop and just loop back if one of the responses is present.

Comment: I edited my post with the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason i want to do this is that clicking on 'X' opens up another powershell prompt that i dont recognize and closing the 'X' exits my script.

When you cancel (or close) the prompt produced by this statement:

```
$cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Please enter your Operator Credentials", "", "")
```

PowerShell returns `$null` to `$cred`, so in the first command expression inside the `try` statement ends up passing `$null` as an argument to `-Credential`:

```bsh
$ADauth = Get-ADGroupMember <# ... #> -Credential $cred
#                                                  ^
#                                       This is now $null
```

Passing `$null` to a `[pscredential]`-typed parameter will cause PowerShell to prompt the user for credentials, **which is why you see a second credential prompt**!

---

If you want to keep re-prompting the user for credentials until they do, simply `continue` the enclosing `do` loop:

```bsh
do{
  $cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Please enter your Operator Credentials", "", "")
  if(-not $cred){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Credentials cannot be empty!")
    # Start over
    continue
  }

  # ...

  $done = $true
} until ($done)
```

**Note: `$PWD` is an automatic variable, use another variable name for your flag (I used `$done` above)**